# How to use a full text index with different lucene analyzers for indexing and searching in neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

For certain use cases, e.g. with NGram or EdgeNGram tokenizers, it should be possible to define 2 different analyzers for a manual index, one for the index task and one for the search/query task.

Comment: you have to create multiple indexes,  one per lucene analyzer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported in Neo4j (as of 3.5.11). The [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/schema/index/#schema-index-fulltext-search-manage) states:

> ... Supported settings are 'analyzer', for specifying what analyzer to use when indexing and querying. ...

Neo4j doesn't provide a way to configure the analyzers (apart from specifying which analyzer to use, or [deploying completely custom analyzer](https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2019/09/06/custom-fulltext-analyzer.html)) so you would seldom want to define different analyzers for indexing and search.

In contrast full text search engines such as Elastic Search allow you to define individual steps in the analyzer. Then it makes sense to allow to define index analyzer and search analyzer differently (although I would argue this is rare and if it happens they are usually very similar anyway).